# JWT Introspection middleware with a Web API - Java and Identity Server

Tags: java, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am currently using Identity Server 4 which is .Net Core based to issue JWT tokens.  I have a .Net Core web api that has middleware in order for the JWT to be validated in the `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5005";
                    options.Audience = "api1";
                });
```

As we can see, its not asking for much except the location of the token server and who the api is which is `api1.  Obviously, its doing some more complex things under the hood.

I found a Java based equivalent to the middleware above, which validates a JWT:

```
String token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhdXRoMCJ9.AbIJTDMFc7yUa5MhvcP03nJPyCPzZtQcGEp-zWfOkEE";
RSAPublicKey publicKey = //Get the key instance
RSAPrivateKey privateKey = //Get the key instance
try {
    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(publicKey, privateKey);
    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
        .withIssuer("auth0")
        .build(); //Reusable verifier instance
    DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
} catch (JWTVerificationException exception){
    //Invalid signature/claims
}
```

This is from [HERE](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) as was recommended by the `jwt.io` site.

Basically I want to be able to implement something in Java that is doing the same thing as the .Net Core code above, but its clearly asking for things like a `Public` and `Private` key that I have no idea how to provide at this point, as the JWT is coming through the header of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, the Microsoft JWT middleware is going to IdentityServer's discovery endpoint and loading in configuration such as the issuer and JWKS (public keys). The discovery document is always hosted on `/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

To validate the token, you will at least need the public keys from the JWKS. In the past I've loaded it it using the jwks-rsa library: https://www.scottbrady91.com/Kotlin/JSON-Web-Token-Verification-in-Ktor-using-Kotlin-and-Java-JWT

When validating the access token, as a minimum, you'll also need to check the token's audience (is the token intended for you) and if it has expired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we will have a read of the link you sent.  Already, you have shed some light on this, since we were not aware of the JWKS.  In fact, I can now see it in the discovery document `.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks`.